# best way to access database using SOAP

Tags: c#, web-services, architecture, soap

I am currently working to understand SOAP protocol with C#, I find some examples in Google and understand the envelope, header, body.

I authenticate with the webservice but I want to know where can I to implement a class or method to access a database with the user and password provided, I mean, soap header has user="john" pass="odos223kiwi0X" the server received the header, now access to database with the user provided and check the password.

if a right option create a custom method in the soap Class to do it?

Comment: I'd recommend using Windows Communication Foundation to abstract the nitty gritty details of SOAP implementation so that you can focus on just writing the code you need to handle your business logic

Comment: It's not clear what technology you are using here. Have you implemented the entire service stack yourself? Or are you using asmx services?

Comment: hi MattDavey! I am using asmx services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a class just as the following :

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Net;

[System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(
Name = "FunctionName",
Namespace = "nameSpace")]
public class ClassName:
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol
{
    public ClassName(string uri) // Constractor
    {
        this.Url = uri; // the full path for your server we  will make later on in the answer
    }

    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute(
    "nameSpace/ClassName",
    RequestNamespace = "nameSpace",
    ResponseNamespace = "nameSpace",
    Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal,
    ParameterStyle = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]

    public object[] FunctionName(string Parameter1)
    {
        object[] results = { };

        try
        {
            results = this.Invoke("FunctionName", new object[] { Parameter1});
            return ((object[])(results[0]));
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            object[] webException = { -1, error.Message };
            return (webException);
        }
    }
}
```

and now we create the asmx service:

create a web service and add this under the namespace :

```
[WebService(Namespace = "NameSpace")] //same namespace you wrote in the class
```

then add your function and Object[] as returning value.

```
[WebMethod]
public object[] FunctionName(string Parameter1) // function name and parameters should be the same in your class where you called the web service (case sensitive)
{
   ... // your code
}
```

** you can download http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp  that will allow you to see and trace the out going requests

please send me back if you need any farther info.

Comment: -1: why not use "Add Service Reference", or "Add Web Reference" if stuck at .NET 2.0?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, I was looking for the easiest way to call a service too. I tried both `Add Web Reference` (which does not work in VS 2010 anymore) and `Add Service reference`. I also looked at wsdl.exe and svcutil.exe. All 4 methods generate massive code for me. The service that I am calling has 634 methods but I only need one method. so I just took Arrabi's answer because the code is more readable (which is actually part of the code generated by wsdl.exe minus Async parts).

Comment: @BobSort: why does the amount of code in Reference.cs matter to you? What usually matters is the size of the code that _you_ have to maintain, not the size of the code that is generated for you.

Comment: It is not usual specially when you are generating code for machines with smaller memory. On the other hand 10 years ago we were thinking `Add Web Reference` is the best and yet it become obsolete. In 10 years I rather explain a 12 line code to my programmers than explaining how a 640Kb source file  created and they cannot create such file anymore. And yes not only we have programs running since 2005 but also we have programs coded in 1990s

Comment: also check this question for a few more reasons why you need to understand the code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132720/method-xyz-cannot-be-reflected