# Why can't WSDL type provider disambiguate overload?

Tags: f#, wsdl, type-providers

From

```
#r "FSharp.Data.TypeProviders"
#r "System.ServiceModel"

open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders

[<Literal>]
let serviceAddress = "http://localhost/Microsoft/Dynamics/GP/eConnect/mex"

type Dynamics = WsdlService<serviceAddress>
type DynTypes = Dynamics.ServiceTypes.SimpleDataContextTypes
type Address = System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress
```

No matter what I do WSDL type provider can't disambiguate the function call:

```
let svc: DynTypes.eConnectClient = Dynamics.GeteConnectServiceEndpoint()
let svc2 = (Dynamics.GeteConnectServiceEndpoint : unit -> DynTypes.eConnectClient)()
let svc3 = (Dynamics.GeteConnectServiceEndpoint : Address -> DynTypes.eConnectClient)(Address serviceAddress)
```

None of them works.

Disabling the other Endpoints and leaving only the one for eConnectClient solves the problem, but I don't even know if I may end up needing the other endpoints.

Comment: I'm leaning on the idea that this might be a bug in the WSDL type provider. It seems if you have multiple endpoints with different contracts the WSDL type provider gives you all the methods for each different endpoints yet gives overloads for each of those endpoints with different return types matching all the other endpoints.

Comment: I could be wrong here but I think C# & F# would disallow overloads with identical type signature for the arguments even though the return types would be different, yet this could be possible in .NET framework which the WSDL type provider seems to be able to generate.

Comment: I found a bunch of problems like this when I tried the WSDL type provider. IIRC, they are often issues with the underlying C# code generator rather than anything specific to F# and type providers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Method 'XYZ' cannot be reflected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132720/method-xyz-cannot-be-reflected)

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with the schema or the type provider, but overloads are not supported by WSDL standard. If the WSDL is generated at runtime from the implementation (as is often the case), the runtime might produce such an invalid WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get past this problem by using reflection to find the method I wanted to invoke, and invoked it dynamically.

```
let noteServiceType = typedefof<NoteService>
let creatorMethod =
    noteServiceType.GetMethods() 
    |> Seq.filter (fun staticMethod -> 
        staticMethod.Name = "GetCustomBinding_IIntakeNoteManager" 
        && staticMethod.ReturnType = typedefof<NoteService.ServiceTypes.SimpleDataContextTypes.IntakeNoteManagerClient>
        && staticMethod.GetParameters().Length = 0)
    |> Seq.toList

let creatorMethod = creatorMethod |> Seq.head

let client = creatorMethod.Invoke(null, [||]) :?> NoteService.ServiceTypes.SimpleDataContextTypes.IntakeNoteManagerClient
```