# Method notesservicev1.exportNotes can not be reflected

Tags: web-services, exception, c#-4.0, reflection

We have consumed a third party web service and are trying to invoke it from an winform application. However when I instantiate the web service the following System.InvalidOperationException exception is thrown:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled

Method notesservicev1.exportNotes can not be reflected.

The XML element 'GetNotesInfoRequest' from namespace
'http://www.excelacom.com/century/cm/notes/service/webservice/request/v1'
references a method and a type.
Change the method's message name using WebMethodAttribute or change the
type's root element using the XmlRootAttribute.
```

I got a link:

[Method 'XYZ' cannot be reflected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132720/method-xyz-cannot-be-reflected)

But I am not getting what exactly I should do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the above link I get the solution.

GetNotesInfoRequest is used by two Web Service methods as there RequestElementName. That's why I was getting the ambiguity.

Thanks :)